# should I use aes ctr mode?

Tags: aes, ctr-mode

I have a question. For example I have text: "The quick brown fox jumps over the dog!"

It has 32 letters. If I  `encrypt` the first 16 letters with 
key: "11111111111111111111111111111111" 
and 
nonce: "1111111111111111" 
and next 16 letters with the same key and nonce will it be `secure`?

Comment: https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/33846/is-regular-ctr-mode-vulnerable-to-any-attacks

Comment: @arghol I've already read this post. Question still there